# Syntax error and unknown None after I call it

Tags: python

I am learning Python for 2 weeks now and tried to do a project alone without any help and got stuck in this syntax error.

My second code shows everything ok but at the end it says None. Why do I get that message if I didn't return anything in my code?

The idea of the code is to create a coin flipping game where the player has to bet money on heads or tails and at the end it has to show the total sum of money he has.

PS: Go easy on me, I probably have some big mistakes. :(

## FIRST CODE

```
    import random
    
    money = 100
    
    def heads(bet):
        num = random.randint(1, 10)
        
       if (num % 2== 0):
          
          print("It's heads and you won " + str(bet) + " In total you have " + str(money_w))
          
           money_w= money + bet
          
         
       else:
         
           print("It's tails you lost " + str(bet) + " In total you have " + str(money_l))
         
            money_l= money - bet
             
           
      
      
    def tails(bet):
         num = random.randint(1, 10)
      
         if (num % 2== 0):
             print("It's tails you won " + str(bet) + " In total you have " + str(money_w)  
      
           money_w= money + bet

         elif:
          
          print("It's heads and you lost " + str(bet) + " In total you have " + str(money_l))
          
          money_l= money - bet
```

## SECOND CODE

```
     def coin_flip(guess, bet):
         result= random.randint(1,2)
      
         if (guess == "Heads" and result == 1) or (guess == "Tails" and result ==2):
             print("You guessed correctly! You won " + str(bet))
      
      else:
          print("You didn't guess. You lost " + str(bet))
```

Comment: When do you get this unexpected `None`? It's not clear in what sequence you are running this code as there are only functions. Please add the code that actually calls the function you are having trouble with. Also please edit your question to remove all those backticks everywhere. Finally, `money_l` and `money_w` are used before they are defined in your code...?

Comment: Welcome, please describe what the output of your function should be. Remember that if a function should return something, you need to add `return`. Be sure you understand the difference between `return` and `print`

Comment: Why are the keywords in your code surrounded by back-ticks? Please copy-and-paste directly from your code editor into your question, then highlight the code and click the `{}` button. We should be able to run the code that you show in your question.

Comment: All these backticks will make the code to not work at all.

Comment: how do you run it ? If you don't use `return` in function then it use `return None` as default. If you use it in `print( function() )` then it will `None`. Or if you use this function in python shell or shell in IDLE then it automatically display result of last function to make life easier.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Comment: Why are the keywords quoted (e.g. `\`def\``, `\`if\``, `\`print\``)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few notes to help you:

- Remove the backticks (`) from the keywords
- Indent the code consistently
- The print statements are referencing `money_w` and `money_l` before they are declared; flip those two statements
- `tails()` and `heads()` don't update `money` or return anything, so `money` will always be 100